# Create but not start a task with a custom task factory?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'd like to be able to create a task without starting it, similar to running `var a = new Task(); a.Start();` but with a custom factory.  Factories provide `StartNew()`, but I can't find a method to separate the two actions.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `TaskFactory` is basically two sets of default options (creation and continuation), a default cancellation token, and a task scheduler.

You can specify the cancellation token and the creation options when you just new up a task - and then start it on whatever scheduler you want. So:

```
Task task = new Task(action,
                     factory.CancellationToken,
                     factory.CreationOptions);
...
task.Start(factory.Scheduler);
```

should do the job other than continuation options. The continuation options are only relevant when you add a continuation anyway, which you can specify directly. Is there anything which isn't covered by this?

(One thing to note is that the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern generally revolves around "hot" tasks which are started by the time you see them anyway. So you probably want to avoid exposing the unstarted tasks too widely.)

Comment: This makes the creation of the factory redundant as we're modifying task behavior manually at task creation (and continuation) time.  I was hoping there was a more elegant method that I've overlooked, but if not I suppose that's good to know too =)

Comment: @Jake: Well, you might want to keep the factory there just as a way of encapsulating those options - or to start other tasks immediately. My point is that it's not really doing much that you can't do manually.