# How can I queue the Task result of an async method without running it?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, task-queue

If I have a class that holds a Queue of Tasks to be executed later, AND I have an `async Task<T>` method, how can I enqueue that async method without executing it?

I want to "delay" this task, and be sure the caller sees it run later just as if it was awaited there in the method body. --- The caller should not know that I have enqueue the task for later.

Right now, if my queue is full, I construct and return new a `Task<T>` here that is not running, which is returning the `.Result` of my private async method:

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(T transaction) {
    if (mustDelay) {
        Task<T> task = new Task<T>(t => executeAsync((T) t).Result, transaction);
        enqueue(task);
        return await task;
    }
    return await executeAsync(transaction);
}

private async Task<T> executeAsync<T>(T transaction) {
    await someWork();
    return transaction;
}
```

When some other task completes, I Dequeue and `Start()` that enqueued task:

```
dequeuedTask.Start();
```

Does this ensure the caller sees the same synchronization as if just returning the awaited result from the method?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143948/create-but-not-start-a-task-with-a-custom-task-factory

Comment: `I have a class that holds a Queue of Tasks to be executed later,` That's the problem you need to fix.  Don't do that.

Comment: @ThomasChristof That going to cause a world of problems at best, and simply won't work at worst.

Comment: What is the queue actually doing?  That will determine how best to design it to properly signal when work should be done.

Comment: Typically you don't; running an `async` method gives you back a "hot" task; that is, the task is started, and it has already run up to the point of the first await that awaited a non-completed awaitable. If you want to defer the action of a method until later, typically you'd wrap it in a `Func` (and maybe wrap the `Func` in a `Lazy`) and then await the invocation of the `Func`.

Comment: In short: don't confuse the "I want a value computed on demand" monad -- `Func`, the "I want a value computed on demand and cached" monad -- `Lazy` -- and the "I want a value computed in the future that calls me back when its ready" -- `Task` -- monad. They're all similar, obviously, and they all compose with each other, but they are logically distinct.

Comment: Any help still? --- @eric-lippert: I understand some advice. These transactions are just glorified Tasks with a Name and Description essentially: should run and report when done. The queue exists to limit the number of concurrent transactions. There is a TaskScheduler example in the .NET API docs: I took that and used it to run ALL tasks like this: `return await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        async () => await executeAsync(transaction),
        transaction.CancellationToken,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        scheduler)
        .Unwrap();`

Comment: @StevenCoco If you want to get help you're going to need to provide more information about your problem.  As it is, there simply isn't enough information to provide a solution, as you haven't provided enough information about what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I queue the Task result of an async method without running it?

Short answer: you can't. Calling an `async` method executes that method. It necessarily *will* start running. If you want to be able to defer the call, you need to wrap it in something that will do that.

One example might be `Func<Task<T>>`, except that the little tiny bit of code you deigned to share with us suggests you want to be able to return a promise (`Task<T>`) as well that represents this call you'll make in the future. You can wrap the whole thing in another task, like in your example code, but IMHO that's a pretty heavy-handed approach, since it ties up (and possibly creates new) a thread pool thread just for the purpose of calling the `async` method.

A better way (IMHO) to accomplish that is to use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. You can store a `Func<Task>` in a queue, which uses the return value to set the `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, then when you decide you can start the task, invoke the `Func<Task>`.

Something like:

```
public Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(T transaction) {
    if (mustDelay) {
        TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        enqueue(async () =>
        {
            tcs.SetValue(await executeAsync(transaction));
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    return executeAsync(transaction);
}
```

Note that here, there's no need for `ExecuteAsync<T>()` to be `async`. You either return the `TaskCompletionSource<T>`'s task, or the task returned by the `executeAsync<T>()` method (by the way, having two methods with names that differ only in letter-casing is IMHO a **horrible** idea).

Note also that your queue will store `Func<Task>` objects, or maybe even `Action` objects (it's generally frowned upon `async void` methods such as the anonymous method above, but you didn't show any exception handling in the first place, so maybe you'll find it works fine in this case). When you dequeue an item, you'll invoke that delegate. Depending on your needs, this will either be "fire-and-forget" (if you store `Action` delegates) or the method that dequeues and invokes the delegate may await the return value of the delegate (if you are storing `Func<Task>` delegates).

Unfortunately, your question is fairly vague. So it's not possible to offer much more than this. If you need additional help, please improve the question so it includes a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're trying to accomplish and what specifically you're having trouble figuring out, along with an appropriate explanation to describe that in detail.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. I have taken your advice and the comment @EricLippert made also: I am refactoring the implementation to take in a Func and will wrap and execute the Func on a TaskScheduler --- and the job of enqueueing "delayed" tasks will be on the Scheduler. The API makes more sense that way (instead of "async all the way down" from the consumer, the consumer will just provide a Func, and the implementation will async it).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified example:

```
async Task<T> GetResult<T>()
{
    DoRightAway();
    await DoLater();
    return DoEvenLater();
}

Task<T> task = GetResult<T>();
//task is running or complete
```

You'd like to defer `GetResult<T>()`'s execution by getting the incomplete task that it represents.  The problem is that calling an `async` method starts running it, even when you don't`await` the call.  The method runs to the first `await`, which is `await DoLater()` in this example.

To understand why you can't get the task represented by an `async` method without running it, consider the following three concepts:

- A `Func` object represents an unstarted computation.
- A new `Lazy` object represents an unstarted computation that will run once.
- A call to an `async` method represents an eventual computation.

Each of these concepts is distinct, but they can be composed with one another into combined representations.  Our `GetResult<T>()` call is an example of the third concept.  It will continue execution when its result is ready, either via `await` or `ContinueWith`.  In our case, we don't even want to start that execution.  Instead, we need to combined the first and third concepts into one representation.  That is, we need an *unstarted* computation (`Func`) that, when it finally does start (`async` method call), will *eventually* complete.

Putting this insight into practice, we solve our problem by wrapping `GetResult<T>()`'s body in a `Func`.

```
Func<Task<T>> GetFactory()
{
    return async () =>
    {
        DoRightAway();
        await DoLater();
        return DoEvenLater();
    }
}
```

We call this new method to get the function:

```
Func<Task<T>> function = GetFactory();
```

Congratulations!  We got the task without running it!  Well, sort of.  We have a function that wraps the (yet to be created) task.  When ready to create and run the task, then we invoke the function:

```
Task<T> task = function();
```

We ensure the task is completed and get its result:

```
T result = await task;
```